# C# Multi-threading logical error

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I am new to multi-threading, but I don't know what's wrong with my code:

```
public int k;
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    k = 10;
    ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(2, 6);
    ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(2, 6);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(aki); 
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(aki);
}

public void aki(object ab)
{
    do
        {
           this.SetText1(textBox1.Text +
           " thread     " + Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode() +
           "               valu=   " + k + Environment.NewLine);
            k--;
        } while (k > 0);
        if (k < 0) Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();    
}
```

For the above, I am getting the following output:

```
 thread     11               valu=   10
 thread     11               valu=   8
 thread     11               valu=   6
 thread     11               valu=   4
 thread     11               valu=   2
 thread     10               valu=   0
```

I am expecting an output in 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0

Please guide me on what is wrong with this.

I am trying to run two threads at a time.

What to do?

EDIT: After rohit's answer, I tried this but i got the following output:

```
 thread     11               valu=   10
 thread     12               valu=   9
 thread     12               valu=   8
 thread     11               valu=   7
 thread     11               valu=   6
 thread      6               valu=   7
 thread      6               valu=   6
 thread      6               valu=   5
 thread     13               valu=   3
 thread     14               valu=   2
 thread     14               valu=   1
```

In this run, 7 and 6 are repeating twice.

Comment: 1) Don't ever abort a pool thread

Comment: 2) Your `SetText1()` might be thread-safe but even reading `textBox1.Text` is unsafe from a thread.

Comment: So what should i use instead of Abort...??

Comment: In this case, a simple `return;` or `break;` statement is enough.

Comment: Please have a look on question again, added a new issue...

Comment: Your new output shows > 2 threads, that's not the code from the answer.

Comment: Yeah i have increased the thread count to 6. Will increasing thread count will be a problem..?

Comment: It just makes discussing and answering harder.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34293/discussion-between-user2205066-and-henk-holterman)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is both thread working on same instance variable `k` of your class.
So, when `one thread modifies` the value, it `gets reflected in other thread`.
The output will always be indeterministic. Like i got this output -

```
 thread     18               valu=   10
 thread     21               valu=   10
 thread     18               valu=   9
 thread     18               valu=   7
 thread     18               valu=   6
 thread     18               valu=   5
 thread     18               valu=   4
 thread     18               valu=   3
 thread     18               valu=   2
 thread     18               valu=   1
 thread     21               valu=   8
```

You should used local variable inside `aki` method -

```
public void aki(object ab)
{
    int k = 10; // <---- HERE
    do
        {
           this.SetText1(textBox1.Text +
                          " thread     " + Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode() +
                          "               valu=   " + k + Environment.NewLine);
            k--;
        } while (k >= 0); // It should be less than and equal to 0 to print 0.
        if (k < 0) Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();    
}
```

Comment: Why you want to put `lock`? It won't let other thread to do processing paralley.

Comment: I need lock so this does not happen...

 [code]thread     11               valu=   10
 thread     12               valu=   9
 thread     12               valu=   8
 thread     11               valu=   7
 thread     11               valu=   6
 thread     6               valu=   7
 thread     6               valu=   6
 thread     6               valu=   5
 thread     13               valu=   3
 thread     14               valu=   2
 thread     14               valu=   1